# change the font color of selected option dropdown angular js

Tags: angularjs

In JQuery , If I want to change the font color of drop-down option after selecting its value, It should be happen like below :

```
 $(this).find('option:selected').css('color', '#a1c3d2');
```

But I want same thing in angular js 1.X

Thank you.

Comment: You can use ngClass

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-style`

More information on how to use it:

[ngStyle Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="value">
 <option ng-repeat="single in [1,2,3,4,5]"  ng-class="single== value ? 'red': ''"> {{single}}</option>
</select>
```